# Presto SQL Server catalog not showing user defined tables

Tags: sql-server, presto

I have two SQL Server catalogs. One of the SQL Server catalogs is showing tables only from master on execution of following commands whereas the other SQL Server catalog displays all the user defined tables.

Why the two catalog is behaving differently?

```
select * from ib.sys.tables;

show tables from ib.dbo;
```

Comment: And by *catalog* you probably mean a **database** - right? Or do you mean a *schema* inside a database? *Catalog* is not a term typically used in the SQL Server community.....

Comment: @marc_s term catalog is used in Presto to define connection string, in order establish connection to a particular database. http://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/current/connector/sqlserver.html

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in configuration (user + default instance) of presto sql server connector.

user used to create catalog have different set of permission /default schema and default data base  .